# What is the difference between .ASCIIZ and DB

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to teach myself Assembly, and my book had me originally writing any string as something like `BPrompt DB 'Enter the value of B: ','$'`, yet when I look up other programs for reference, I see lines like `BPrompt: .asciiz "Enter the value of B:"`.
Should I be using one over the other?  I read up on .asciiz far enough to know it makes .ascii obsolete, but I see no mention of using DB.  I'm using MASM if that makes a difference.

Comment: `.asciiz` is very similar to `db`, but it includes a terminating zero character. So `var db "test",0` is identical to `var: .asciiz "test"`.

Comment: Does the '$' take place of the 0 in your 'var db "test",0'?  Or do those do different things?

Comment: They are different things. `\0` is the C programming language ending char while `$` is the MS-DOS ending char.

Comment: Oh okay I understand.  I've been running my programs through MS-DOS so I'll stick with $!  Thank you very much!